# How to implement a prompt when entering a command in aiogram Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, aiogram

How to implement a tooltip when entering a command in aiogram Python?

You enter a command in a line and a small field is shown as a tooltip, example below.

[image: Photo example]

I've tried googling for information, documentation, but I haven't really found what I'm looking for

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what it should look like, there's no code or anything in there

How can I get the point across differently if you don't understand what I mean and what it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *tooltip* you're searching for is called Inline Mode.

In order to enable it for your bot:

1. Contact [BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather)
2. Type in "/mybots"
3. Choose your bot
4. Click on "Bot Settings"
5. Click on "Inline Mode"
6. And finally click on "Turn on"

Then you'll have the option to edit the inline placeholder that will be shown in the chat.

[BotFather](https://i.stack.imgur.com/424tC.png)